# Show picture on picture

Tags: javascript, onclick, toggle, delay

I am having some trouble on my final. All my img's are set to 0 opacity and change when clicked (opacity 1). My design calls for when the button is clicked, i would have an additional image to show over the top of it with a 1 second delay. IE describing each layer/img shown. And when the user clicks off they both go with it and a new slide appears, and then 1 second delay a new description is shown of that layer.

Here is my current js code:

```
window.onload = intialize;
function intialize(){
    var suit = document.getElementById("man").getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
    var undies = document.getElementById("man").getElementsByTagName("img")[1];
    var naked = document.getElementById("man").getElementsByTagName("img")[2];

    var suit = document.getElementById("layernav").getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    var undies = document.getElementById("layernav").getElementsByTagName("a")[1];
    var naked = document.getElementById("layernav").getElementsByTagName("a")[2];   

//initial load suit
    showSuit();

    suit.onclick = showSuit;
    undies.onclick = showUndies;
    naked.onclick = showNaked;
}


function showSuit(){
    var suit = document.getElementById("man").getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
    var undies = document.getElementById("man").getElementsByTagName("img")[1];
    var naked = document.getElementById("man").getElementsByTagName("img")[2];

    suit.style.opacity = "1";
    undies.style.opacity ="0";  
    fbnaked.style.opacity ="0"; 
}

function showUndies(){
    var suit = document.getElementById("man").getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
    var undies = document.getElementById("man").getElementsByTagName("img")[1];
    var naked = document.getElementById("man").getElementsByTagName("img")[2];

    suit.style.opacity = "0";
    undies.style.opacity ="1";
    naked.style.opacity ="0";   
}

function showNaked(){
    var suit = document.getElementById("man").getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
    var undies = document.getElementById("man").getElementsByTagName("img")[1];
    var naked = document.getElementById("man").getElementsByTagName("img")[2];

    suit.style.opacity = "0";
    undies.style.opacity ="0";
    naked.style.opacity ="1";   
}
```

Two questions, one how is this possible adding add to this code. Second, is there short hand for this growing JS, because my layers are now getting lengthy.

Thank you in advance, im truly exhausted and its so close to being done well or not at all.

Cheers!

I feel like it could look something like this too, i just cant piece it:

http://jsfiddle.net/gtU56/2/

Whether a click or a delay, im just trying layer in a second img/description. Any Ideas?

Comment: the initialize function looks a bit wrong - why are suit, undies, naked all defined twice?

Comment: I don't understand your 1st question. Can you explain what the problem is with the code - what does it not do that you want it to do?

Answer (score 1):

To make images overlap you possibly need `position: relative` or `position: absolute`, as well as `zindex` in css.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

For shorthand I recommend you to simply create a function that do the entire `document.getElementById("man").getElementsByTagName("img")` part. Or if you could, just use jQuery, which can be done easily with

```
var suit = $("#man img")[0];
```

http://jquery.com/

To do 1 second delay use `setTimeout`

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Comment: The CSS is down pat. What i need is an second image to appear over the first one selected. So one PNG that appears as like "Suit" and another PNG that appears on a delay and is a "description" PNG. Once you navigate away same senario on another slide.

Answer (score 1):

For the question on reducing code length, I always include a function with a short name to replace `document.getElementById`, like:

```
function E(i) {return document.getElementById(i)}
```

With frameworks like jquery this is already provided. Your current code could be reduced pretty easily using an additional function to avoid some of the repetition.

```
function E(i) {
    return document.getElementById(i)
}
window.onload = intialize;

function intialize() {
    var n = E('layernav').getElementsByTagName('a');
    showSuit();
    n[0].onclick = showSuit;
    n[1].onclick = showUndies;
    n[2].onclick = showNaked;
}

function setManOpacity(op0, op1, op2) {
    var i = E('man').getElementsByTagName('img');
    i[0].style.opacity = op0;
    i[1].style.opacity = op1;
    i[2].style.opacity = op2;
}

function showSuit() {
    setManOpacity(1, 0, 0);
}

function showUndies() {
    setManOpacity(0, 1, 0);
}

function showNaked() {
    setManOpacity(0, 0, 1);
}​
```

Comment: Something is off, i cant see it.

Comment: If you want to  do the same but with lots of layers you should use loops, for instance like this http://jsfiddle.net/T6VqY/